# Can't connect using setsockopt in python

Tags: python, network-programming

I am new to python. So the question seems silly.

I want to implement a simple program for client and server in python.

The server.py is

```
import socket
#s = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "wlan0"+'\0')
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c,addr = s.accept()
    print "Got connection from",addr
    c.send("Thank you for connecting")
    c.close()
```

The client.py is

```
import socket
#s = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "wlan0"+'\0')
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.connect((host,port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

The problem is that compiler is showing an error "operation is not permitted". I tried executing program as root. The error is gone, But client and server connection was not made.

Everything works fine before adding this line

```
   s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "wlan0"+'\0')
```

Hope somebody can aswer my problem.
I want to connect client and server through wlan0 interface.

Thanks.

Comment: ***Client and server on the same machine? Wired and wireless in the same ip range? Wlan network server ip dynamic?***

Comment: client and server are in the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server PY:

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
#s = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)




def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

host = get_ip_address("eth0")#replace with "wlan0"
port = 12345
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c,addr = s.accept()
    print "Got connection from",addr
    c.send("Thank you for connecting")
    c.close()
```

Client PY:

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

#s = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = get_ip_address("eth0")#replace with "wlan0"
port = 12345
s.connect((host,port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

[check this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439094-get-the-ip-address-associated-with-a-network-inter/).
**warning :** Server py run on shell("python server.py") and client run on idle.